# Testing a Controller in a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I would like to see suggestions if my code could be more improved. In my controller I have a line:

```
self.bool_value = False  # for testing
```

which in my opinion should not be there, because I put it there only for testing purposes, but I did not find any way around. In addition I would like to know whether you guys test the `__init__` method as well, because I see no point in it. And another question would be, if you guys would test if the parameter `req` was called in the execute method. Any other suggestions to improve this code are welcomed.

My Controller looks like this:

```
from typing import Callable
from source.controller.RequestModel import RequestModel
from source.boundaries.AbstractInputBoundary import       AbstractInputBoundary


class Controller:

abstractInputBoundary: AbstractInputBoundary
bool_function: Callable[[bool], bool]
bool_value: bool

def __init__(self, abstract_input_boundary, bool_function=lambda _:     True):
    self.abstractInputBoundary = abstract_input_boundary
    self.bool_function = bool_function
    self.bool_value = True

def process_input(self) -> None:
    """
    Waits for the input of the User in order to call a usecase
    :rtype: None
    """
    while self.bool_function(self.bool_value):
        self.bool_value = False  # for testing
        inp: str = input()

        if inp == "show data":
            req = RequestModel()
            req.setRequest(inp)
            self.abstractInputBoundary.execute(req)
```

My Test looks like the following:

```
import unittest
from source.controller.Controller import Controller
from unittest.mock import patch
from unittest.mock import MagicMock


class TestController(unittest.TestCase):

def test_process_input(self):
    """
    This tests, whether after the input "show data" in the controller object a boundary object is called
    """

    def switch_function(switch_bool):
        if switch_bool is True:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    with patch('builtins.input') as inp:
        inp.return_value = "show data"
        boundary = MagicMock()
        boundary.execute = MagicMock()
        controller = Controller(boundary, switch_function)
        controller.process_input()
        assert boundary.execute.called
```